# Tyepscript `Final` or `const` for function parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to have function parameters as `readonly` or `const` Basically:

```
const someMethod = (arg1: string) => {
   arg1 = 'hello'; // should error out
}
```

`readonly` only applies to class methods right? I tried to create a `type` and use `readonly` there with no luck either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way in TypeScript to prevent reassignment to a function parameter.

If you're using TSLint, you can turn on the [no-parameter-reassignment](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-parameter-reassignment/) rule.

Comment: Ah, that's useful. Good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, but you can store this argument in constant variable and use it further, and this variable can't be changed anymore:

```
const someMethod = (arg1: string) => {
   const yourVariable: string = arg1;
   yourVariable = 'hello'; // the error will occur
}
```